# HIDE and SHOW a href by id

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a problem with a js that hide a link with toggle(). 
The problem is:

I get a list of business and each business has a phone number hiden on a a href link.
When one link is clicked instead show only the number of the link clicked is shown all number of all links
my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").css('display', 'none')
    $("a").click( function(){
        $("p").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

i know why, but i dont know how to do to show by id. Im using php.

```
<div id='phone'><a href='#' id='$eid'>Veja nosso telefone!

<p".$e2['telefone']."/>
```

`$eid` i get from DB.

Comment: That's because you `slideToggle` ALL `p`-elements. Post some more HTML and we can see how you can fix it.

Comment: post your render HTML code.

Comment: and your html snippte is invalid as well... You forgot a few `<` or `>`

Comment: `<p".$e2['telefone']."/>` is invalid. It should be `<p>".$e2['telefone']."</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do this. You can use the `$(this)` selector to tell the interpreter that you want the current element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").css('display', 'none')
     $("a").click( function(){
         $(this).slideToggle('slow'); // would only slidetoggle $(this) which is the element that was just clicked.
     });
});


 <div id='phone'><a href='#' id='$eid'>Veja nosso telefone!

 <p".$e2['telefone']."/>
```

Comment: <script>      $(document).ready(function(){
 $("carrinnho").css('display', 'none')
  $("button").click( function(){
      $(this).slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
</script>       HTML :           <div id='telefone_empresa'>
           <button name='produto' value='$e2[id]' id='adicionar' class='btn_add_carrinho'>Veja nosso telefone</button>
            <div id='carrinho'>
             <font id='num_carro' style='margin-left:45px;' >".$e2['telefone']."</font>
            </div>
          </div>    I would like to show the content in the tag <font:

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("a").click( function(){
    $(this).find("p").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

`this` inside `click` function refers to DOM element being clicked, `find` will get you `p` elements inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I **ASUME** your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id='phone'>
    <a href='#' id='someID01'>Veja nosso telefone!
        <p>012-45567890</p>
    </a>
    <a href='#' id='someID02'>Veja nosso telefone!
        <p>5486</p>
    </a>
    <a href='#' id='someID03'>Veja nosso telefone!
        <p>088-9001</p>
    </a>
    <a href='#' id='someID04'>Veja nosso telefone!
        <p>Secret!</p>
    </a>
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

Then this JavaScript will work

```
$(function () {
    $('#phone > a').click(function (e) {
        // Do not follow the link, even if it's '#'
        e.preventDefault();

        // Toggle it's p-element
        $(this).find('p').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

This script will toggle the `p` elements inside your link when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` to reference classes and `#` to reference IDs. 
Non-prefixed names reference tag types (i.e. `p`, `div`, `span`, etc).
This is true for both css and jQuery.

```
$('.class') // references all instances of class named 'class'.
$('#id') // references item with id = 'id'.
```

See the official [jQuery selector guide](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

All right, let's start with the fact that you don't need to put your javascript to set default styles for your elements.

First, instead of doing this in your javascript:

```
$("p").css('display', 'none');
```

You should use CSS to set the default styles:

```
p{display:none}
```

No unnecessary javascript code leads to better performance for the user.

Second, I'm not sure if #phone is the correct semantic usage of an ID, the usage of ID is for something that would be unique on your markup. So for something that will be used on a listing the semantic choice is class.

So, let's solve your code problem...

First, you markup have some problems too, your p tag is incorrect and your a tag is not closed. Down below is a possible correction to your HTML code:

```
<div class='phone'>
  <a href='#' id='<?= $eid; ?>'>Veja nosso telefone!</a>
  <p><?= $e2['telefone']; ?></p>
</div>
```

With that code to toggle the visibility of the p would work with the following code

```
$('.phone a').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).next().toggle('slow'); // this refer to the A tag that was clicked, and .next() selects the next element on the DOM, which in this case is the P tag
  e.preventDefault(); // it is a good thing to use to avoid the default behavior of the A tag
});
```

For more information on tree traversal methods you can visit: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score -1):

```
$("a").click( function(){
    var myId = $(this).prop("something that gives you the corresponding id, like a classname");
    $("#"+myId).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Too much for my head. You would use 'this' to get the id of an item, only to reference that same item by id in the next line? Also, myId does not net you the ID of $(this), not the way you are doing it.

Comment: He is trying to show a specific 'p' element by clicking an other kind of element. You want to give them the same id ?

Comment: You would have this handler sitting on any link on the page? Seriously? But yes, I finally understood what you are trying to achieve. Storing the necessary ID in a property of the link? Not the most elegant solution, but it can work. I would use DOM hierarchy to achieve the same result.

Comment: If there are other link on the page, you can use the class name, ok. And for storing the ID, the href could be used, like `<a class="foo" href="#bar">phone number</a> ... <p id="bar" />`. With DOM hierarchy, you mean child, parent, find etc... to find the 'p' ?

Comment: Precisely. Use either .next('.hiddenphone') or .parents('.parentclass').find('.hiddenphone'). This way you provide less redundant data. If you want to go into attribute data storage, you should be using the html5 data-* attributes, not href. See http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/. Also, using tag TYPES for reference is hardly a good habit. Use custom class names.